# Android Opening Your Custom files attached to an email app in your App

Tags: android, email, mime-types, file-extension, email-client

There seems to be a few questions based around this on StackOverflow. But many of them are in regards to a file manager. But Android doesn't not ship with one.

In my app I am trying to provide a feature where data could be attached to an email and sent to another user who can then open the attachment in my app.

All of the related answers talk about using a path pattern like

```
 <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext" />
```

But this will not work on Emails and files from Downloads app because they hide the file name when sending to the activity.
Downloads use the following URI path : **/all_Dowloads/xyz**    where xyz is a number
While the email app uses  **/youremail@address/messages/X/attachments/0/1/Best/false**
So you can't use **pathPatterns** on them. Also you have to use

```
  <data android:scheme="content"  />
```

to successfully get the intent to fire, than scheme="file".

ATM I am using

```
<data android:mimeType="*/*" />
```

to test above paths, but it provides my app as an option on every kind of attachment.

```
<data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
```

narrows the types of attachments but it is not ideal.

Is there a way to have your own file type as a mime-type where the extension of my file name would only show my app as option to view the file in.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?  I am tackling the same issue now.